# Alterar URL no localhost (.htaccess)

Tags: php, htaccess, url, xampp, localhost

Gostaria de alterar a URL do meu servidor local. Utilizo o XAMPP.

Acredito que seja necessário criar ou alterar o **.htaccess**. Na verdade, já criei o arquivo e coloquei na raiz do localhost, isto é, no diretório **htdocs**.

Gostaria de faze a seguinte alteração:

De: http://localhost/src/php/estudos/

Para: http://localhost/estudos/

Ou seja, gostaria de remover os diretórios **/src/** e **/php/** da URL. Poderiam me ajudar?

Não compreendi os outros post semelhantes a este. Não estou certo, mas para alterar o .htaccess é preciso uma noção de RegEx da qual careço.

[image: Printscreen dos diretórios]

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Richard, bom dia.

Tenta o seguinte na raiz do htdocs, precisa criar um .htaccess e colocar o código.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ src/php/$1 [L]
```

Comente se deu certo.

Comment: A página fica em HTML básico. Provavelmente porque meu _style.css_ está em outro diretório, certo? Postei a estrutura dos subdiretórios do *htdocs*. Aliás, quando clico em algum de meus links de navegação entre as páginas do site, a URL ainda permanece. Os diretorios somem apenas se digito, por exemplo,  *http://localhost/inicio*. As tags estão direcionando da seguinte forma <a href="/inicio">Página Inicial</a>, <a href="/estudos">Estudos Bíblicos</a> etc.

Comment: Tenta trocar a ultima linha por isso RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ src/php/$1 [L,R=301]